# structs problem: how do I find how many student have same name (in C program)?

Tags: c

What is wrong in this code?
How do I find how many students have the same name?

How do I find out all the number of students who
have same (Duplicate) name spelling (built in function cannot be used).

**Input:**

```
     Enter student name: Hasib
     Enter student name: Hasib
     Enter student name: Jhon
```

The **output** must be like this:

```
2 students have same name
```

**Code:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    char name[20];
};

int main() {
    struct student s[10];
    int i, j, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Enter student name: ");
        gets(s[i].name);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 3; j++) {
            if (s[i].name == s[j].name) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d students have same name\n\n", count);
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your code and tell us which inputs you used and what the result was. But the most basic problem here is that you use `==` to compare strings when you should be using `strcmp`. Also you algorithm does not do what you want.

Comment: @Peter i don't want to use strcmp. I want result without using strcmp

Comment: That makes no sense, please clarify your question, input, desired output, constraints, etc.

Comment: @Drhunter,  `==` is not suited to compare strings in C.

Comment: Never *ever* use `gets`! It's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) it has even been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: As for the comparison issue, `s[i].name == s[j].name` will only work when `i == j`. (which will never happen with your loops). Remember: Arrays decays to *pointers* to their first element. Now try to guess what you're really comparing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- C strings cannot be compared with `==` as you do. You just compare the pointers, not the contents of the arrays. You must include `<string.h>` and use:

  ```
    if (strcmp(s[i].name, s[j].name) == 0) {
        /* duplicate name */
    }
  ```
- Also note that `gets()` must not be used as it may cause undefined behavior if the input is too long. As a matter of fact, attackers may take advantage of this flaw to execute arbitrary code. Use `fgets()` or `scanf("%19s", s[i].name)`.
- Why do you define the `students` array with 10 entries and only use 3 in the rest of the `main()` function?

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
    char name[20];
};

int main() {
    struct student s[10];
    int n, i, j, count;
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        printf("Enter student name: ");
        if (scanf("%19s%*[^\n]", s[n].name) < 1)
            break;
    }
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (strcmp(s[i].name, s[j].name) == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d students have same name\n\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Your counting method is incorrect for more than 3 entries: if the 4 students have the same name, `count` will be incremented for pairs `0,1`, `0,2`, `0,3`, `1,2`, `1,3` and `2,3` hence 6 students with the same name (!).

Here is a corrected version that does not use `strcmp()` either:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    char name[20];
};

int same_string(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    while (*s1 == *s2) {
        if (*s1 == '\0')
            return 1;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    struct student s[10];
    int n, i, j, count;
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        printf("Enter student name: ");
        if (scanf("%19s%*[^\n]", s[n].name) < 1)
            break;
    }
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i != j && same_string(s[i].name, s[j].name)) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d students have same name\n\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. Is there any way to find duplicate without using strcmp()

Comment: @Drhunter Only by creating some actual string comparison code. What is the problem you have with `strcmp`? What do you have against it? You *do* understand what happens when using `==` to attempt to compare strings?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually someone ask me to do this without using strcmp. That is why i am asking for  Is there any way to find duplicate without using strcmp()

Comment: @Drhunter Then you need to implement the string-comparison code yourself. You need to iterate over the two strings and compare them character by character. There are many examples and tutorials about this all over the Internet.

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code, == is not a working commands for strings, We can use Strcmp for the same.

```
  struct student
  {
   char name[20];
   };
 int main(){
   struct student s[10];
   int i,j=0,count,res;
   for(i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
     printf("Enter student name: ");
    gets(s[i].name);
    }
      for(i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
    for(j=i+1; j<3; j++)
    {

     if(strcmp(s[i].name, s[j].name)==0)
    {
        count++;
    }
    }
    } 
    printf("\n%d students have same name\n\n",count);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You may get warning because implicit declaration of function is not allowed...ie for gets & strcmp

Comment: `gets` is a security risk.

Comment: @Anandha i need to the output without using strcmp.